# Forms submit doesn't work in Chrome, ie

Tags: javascript

There are many forms with a unique id

```
<form id='fu_edit_1' method='post' action=''>
....
</form>

<form id='fu_edit_2' method='post' action=''>
....
</form>
```

Use this js code

```
    var formName = 'fu_edit_'+id;
document.forms[formName].submit();
```

so here is the code works fine in ff the last version, but in chrome and ie refused to work. However, if you specify the id of the form directly it works, for example:

```
document.forms["fu_edit_2"].submit();
```

What is wrong?

---

In the console, Chrome writes : **Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'submit'**

Comment: Just to be sure: are you positive that `id` has a value at the point that you construct the `formName` variable?

Comment: where does the `id` variable come from? How is it populated? Have you debugged this code to check whether `formName` is being populated correctly? It seems like you're concatenating the form prefix string with `NaN` or something else other than the numbers of your forms

Comment: I checked the id exists. And in the ff select the desired form.

Comment: can you paste how you are passing  the id ??

Comment: I badly know English, not quite understand what you mean. Look at my question, I updated it.

Comment: Problem solved, using the getelementbyid.

document.getElementById('fu_edit_'+id).submit();

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is with the variable `id` I would recomend you to this:

```
  alert(id.toString());
```

Maybe there is an issue with your number converion to string, perhaps alert will surprise you with something like `01` or similar

Comment: No, everything is as it should be, no 01 and other

Comment: one question, why do you use double quotes on the explicit text but single quotes in the string?, sorry it might sound corky but i've seen so many weird things lately ..

Comment: It happened during experiments

Answer (score 0):

I've come across this problem multiple times and finally found that if you have a form element in the fu_edit_2 form with a name attribute of submit then document.forms["fu_edit_2"].submit would be a reference to the element and not a method to submit the form. I've found it best to stay away from having any form fields with a name of submit to circumvent this problem.